# Create a NSString from different class

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsstring

I have a method that receive from a SOAP method a result as:

```
SDZPaymentResult* result = (SDZPaymentResult*)value;
```

If I use: `NSLog(@"%@", result);`

It shows:

```
<CXMLElement 0x20d9c950 [0x20dccc40] ns1:paymentResult 
<ns1:paymentResult>
<additionalData xmlns="http://payment.services.adyen.com" xsi:nil="true"/>
<authCode xmlns="http://payment.services.adyen.com">76419</authCode>
<dccAmount xmlns="http://payment.services.adyen.com" xsi:nil="true"/>
<dccSignature xmlns="http://payment.services.adyen.com" xsi:nil="true"/>
<fraudResult xmlns="http://payment.services.adyen.com" xsi:nil="true"/>
<issuerUrl xmlns="http://payment.services.adyen.com" xsi:nil="true"/>
<md xmlns="http://payment.services.adyen.com" xsi:nil="true"/>
<paRequest xmlns="http://payment.services.adyen.com" xsi:nil="true"/>
<pspReference xmlns="http://payment.services.adyen.com">8813677969778790</pspReference>
<refusalReason xmlns="http://payment.services.adyen.com" xsi:nil="true"/>
<resultCode xmlns="http://payment.services.adyen.com">Authorised</resultCode>
</ns1:paymentResult>>
```

Have a way to change result into a NSString?

Comment: which data you want as a string ? is it only the link ? or What ? Please explain..

Comment: You were using TBXML, do you still you it ?

Comment: All the result content that is showed.

Comment: @ThilinaHewagama yes, I need to change it to a String and then parse using a XMLParser like TBXML or anyother.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `%@` format specifier calls the `description` method of the object, which will return the `NSString` you are looking for. But you might want to rethink your solution, that's not what the `description` is made for, and if it's not one of your classes, the returned value might change and break your code! Check if there isn't another method to get the data in a more reliable way.

Comment: I have used [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", result]; and it works for now, I have tried to get it in a more reliable way, but the method SDZPaymentResult is broke and It is a very complex code, I will try to recreate a method from this result to work in all way.

Comment: @Marckaraujo Don't use `stringWithFormat:`, invoke the `description` method directly on the object instead.

Answer (score 0):

As @JustSid said, you can use another way:

`NSLog(@"%@", result.description);`

Your way and this way are the same, so if you want to change "result", you have to change return-value of description method, if you want to change it, you have to be owner of class of "result".

I think you have to inherit class of "result" and you can do anything you want!

Answer (score -1):

Use an NSString formatter:

```
NSString *newString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", result];
```

Comment: Not sure why this has been down voted... It's the exact answer that the poster wanted to "Have a way to change result into a NSString?".

Comment: I downvoted you because `stringWithFormat:` isn't needed. It does answer the question, but calling `description` on the object is much more efficient (though it's also not a good practice)